# Measurable extended real valued functions.

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following lemma:
An extended real valued function $f:X\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable if and only if the sets $A = \{x\in X\mid f(x) = +\infty\}, B = \{x\in X\mid f(x) = -\infty\}\in \mathbb{F}$ and the function $g(x) = \begin{cases}f(x)& x\notin A\cup B\\0 & x\in A\cup B\end{cases}$ is measurable. $\mathbb{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Assuming that $f$ is measurable, I'm trying to show that the function $g$ is measurable. I'm thinking that $\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in X\mid g(x) > \alpha\} = \{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid 0>\alpha\}$. Now since $f$ is measurable, then the set $\{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\}\in\mathbb{F}$.

For the set $C = \{x\in X\mid 0>\alpha\}$ if $\alpha < 0$ then $C = X\in\mathbb{F}$ and if $\alpha\geq 0$, then $C = \emptyset\in\mathbb{F}$

I'm not sure if this proof is correct, especially writing out $\{x\in X\mid g(x) > \alpha\} = \{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid 0>\alpha\}$. I would love if someone could clarify this for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot intersecting $A\cup B$ or $(A\cup B)^C$ in the calculation of $\{x\in X\mid g(x) > \alpha\}$.

Take the following sketch as example:

[image]

for any $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$, as from the figure, the set $\{x \in X| -\infty < f(x) \leq \alpha\}$ is disjoint with $\{x \in X| g(x) > \alpha\}$.

---

Here is the original answer with a proof:

Since here the definition of measurable function is not given in the question, I am following the definition in *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden, 4th.

Take any $\alpha$ in $\Bbb{R}$, denote $U_\alpha$ to be the set $\{x\in X\mid g(x) > \alpha\}$.

If $\alpha \geq 0$, then for any $x \in A \cup B$, $x \notin U_\alpha$ for $g(x) = 0 \leq \alpha$. And for any $x \notin A \cup B$, $x \in U_\alpha$ if and only if $f(x) > \alpha$.

Similarly, if $\alpha < 0$, then for any $x \in A \cup B$, $x \in U_\alpha$ for $g(x) = 0 > \alpha$. And for any $x \notin A \cup B$, $x \in U_\alpha$ if and only if $f(x) > \alpha$.

Hence:

$$
U_\alpha = \{x\in X\mid g(x) > \alpha\} \\
\begin{aligned}
=\begin{cases}
(A\cup B)^C \cap \{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\} \text{ if $\alpha \geq 0$}\\
((A\cup B)^C \cap \{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\}) \cup (A \cup B)\text{ if $\alpha < 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

For both cases, $U_\alpha$ is measurable. Hence $g$ is measurable.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'd be glad if you could comment on whether or not the attempt in the question is correct or not and point out the error, if it is incorrect.

Comment: Sure. I think $\{x\in X\mid g(x) > \alpha\} \neq \{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid 0>\alpha\}$. I updated the answer and hope that it's more clear.